# How to change webpage background colour multiple times by clicking on the same button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm an absolute beginner at JavaScript/jQuery.

I was wondering if I could achieve an effect where I can continuously toggle multiple background colours of the webpage by clicking the same button multiple times.

This is the script I found on the Internet:

```
<script>
  $("#change-colour").click(function(){ 
  $("body").css("background-color","red");
  });
</script>
```

However, using this I can change the background colour only once. I wish to change the background colour multiple times by clicking the same button, For example:

Click >> Red >> Click >> Blue >> Click >> Green >> Click >> and then back to Red

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to store the colors somewhere, like an array, and then just use an incrementing variable to get the next color etc, like so:

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'cyan'],
    i = 0;

$("#change-colour").click(function(){ 
    $("body").css("backgroundColor", colors[i++]);
    if (i >= colors.length)
        i = 0;

});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/TZEqL/)

Comment: A bit over the top that ternary given op is a noob. `i++; if (i>=colors.length); i=0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var colours = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
var colourIndex = 0;

$('#change-colour').click(function () {
    // Get the current colour from the array
    var colour = colours[colourIndex];
    // Set the background colour
    $('body').css('background-color', colour);
    // Move the counter along to the next index
    colourIndex = colourIndex + 1;
    // If the counter is pointing past the end of
    // the array, repoint it at the beginning
    if(colourIndex >= colours.length) {
        colourIndex = 0;
    }
});
```